# Calling the function once for two attributes in yii grid view

Tags: php, function, gridview, yii, yii2

I have a common function where I use them for different purposes in my yii grid view. For instance say my attributes are col1 and col2. They both call the same function, based on the value I perform different actions. The function needs to go through millions of data before returning back to my grid view.

I am calling the function twice here once in col1 and once in col2. is there anyway that I can call the function only once and use it for both the attributes, which will be very handy? Any help regarding this will be great.
Thank you.

```
array(
                'header'=>'Phrase Used',
                'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'width:10px;text-align:center;'),
                'value'=> function($data){
                            if($data->usedBankPhrase($data->bank_id) == 1) {echo "<span class=\"translated-badge\" title =\"Used \">u</span>";}
                            else{echo "<span class=\"badge\" style=\"background-color:red !important; padding:2px;\" title =\" Not Used \">nu</span>";}
                            },
                'filter'=>'',
            ),

    //delete button
    'remove' => array(
                        'visible'=>'!$data->usedBankPhrase($data->bank_id);',
                        'label' => 'Delete Phrase',
                        'imageUrl'=>  Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/images/icons/cross.png',
                        'options'=>array('class'=>'full-bank-delete', 'id'=>'\'remove-banker-\'.$data->bank_id'), //HTML options for the button tag.
                    ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In model:

Define property

```
public $storedUsedBankPhrase = null;
```

Create getter:

```
public function getCalculatedUsedBankPhrase() {
   if($this->storedUsedBankPhrase === null) {
      $this->storedUsedBankPhrase= $this->usedBankPhrase($this->bank_id);
   }
   return $this->storedUsedBankPhrase ;
}
```

In GridView use:

```
'value'=> function($data){
           if($data->calculatedUsedBankPhrase == 1) {...
```

Comment: But still I end up calling the function twice right?

Comment: @MohanPrasad yes, but it's calculated one time and it's stored in `$storedUsedBankPhrase` attribute. To be sure change this line `if(!$this->storedUsedBankPhrase) {` to `if($this->storedUsedBankPhrase === null) {` and be sure that your calculating function is not returning null.

Comment: Yes I'll check with that.. Thank you

Comment: @MohanPrasad Remember to upvote and accept answer if it's working ;)

Comment: Shouldn't my second column access the storedUsedBankPhrase? instead of the calculatedUsedBankPhrase?

Comment: No, `getCalculatedUsedBankPhrase()` will return `storedUsedBankPhrase` if its calculated or will calculate it and then return it.

Comment: I used the storedUsedBankPhrase Directly .. It still works.. because It will not be null anyways..

Comment: But it's not right. That's why we wrote `getCalculatedUsedBankPhrase()` function, to do this for u, just use this function to get `storedUsedBankPhrase` or calculate it if it's not set.